# How to upload a value to ESPAsyncWebServer?

Tags: html, c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am trying to upload a variable called 'data' from my ESP32 to a web page hosted on async web server, but I can't find a way to do so.

```
String data = "text";
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
   <p>%data%</p>
</body>
</html>)rawliteral";

server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", index_html);
});
server.on("/data", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/plain", data);
});
```

The variable is not being displayed correctly on the webpage, and just says %data%.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured it out by myself, here is the correct code in case anybody else is interested in this very specific task:

```
    String data = "text";
    const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
    <!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
        body { text-align:center; }
        .vert { margin-bottom: 10%; }
        .hori{ margin-bottom: 0%; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>%DATA%</p>
    </body>
    </html>)rawliteral";

    String processor(const String& var){
      if (var == "DATA"){
        return String(data);
      }
      return String();
    }

    server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
        request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html,processor);
      });
```

Comment: Can i send data via url to webserver. Or any possibility to send external data to async webserver page. From mobile

Comment: What type of data? You can use http GET method to update variables on your ESP board from web browser. Is this what you're looking for?